# Can't combine "LINQ Join" with other tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The main problem is that I recieve the following message:

"base {System.SystemException} = {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'BokButik1.Models.Book-Author'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."}"

based on this LinQ code:

> IBookRepository myIBookRepository = new BookRepository();
>   var allBooks = myIBookRepository.HamtaAllaBocker();
>
> IBok_ForfattareRepository myIBok_ForfattareRepository = new Bok_ForfattareRepository();
>   var Book-Authors = 
>   myIBok_ForfattareRepository.HamtaAllaBok_ForfattareNummer();
>
> var q =
>   from booknn in allBooks
>           join Book-Authornn in Book-Authors on booknn.BookID equals
>           Book-Authornn.BookID
>           select new { booknn.title, Book-AuthorID };

**How shall I solve this problem to get a class instance that contain with property title and Book-AuthorID?**

// Fullmetalboy

I also have tried making some dummy by using "allbooks" relation with Code Samples from the address http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx. Unfortunately, still same problem.

I also have taken account to Int32 due to entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx. Unfortunatley, still same problem.

Using database with 3 tables and one of them is a many to many relationship. This database is used in relation with entity framework

### Book-Author

Book-Author (int)
BookID      (int)
Forfattare  (int)

### Book

BookID     (int)
title       (string)
etc etc etc

Comment: Are you really trying to use a variable or property named `Book-Author`? You do realize that you can't use a `-` in an identifer, right? It gets interpreted as the `subtract` operator.

Comment: Serkan: I have corrected my message with explicit answer.
For everybody: Please inform me if any information is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using two separate linq-to-sql repositories to join against. This won't work. Joins can only work between tables defined in a single repository.

However, if you are happy to bring all of the data into memory then it is very easy to make your code work. Try this:

```
var myIBookRepository = new BookRepository();
var myIBok_ForfattareRepository = new Bok_ForfattareRepository();

var allBooks =
    myIBookRepository.HamtaAllaBocker().ToArray();

var Book_Authors =
    myIBok_ForfattareRepository.HamtaAllaBok_ForfattareNummer().ToArray();

var q =
    from booknn in allBooks
    join Book_Authornn in Book_Authors
        on booknn.BookID equals Book_Authornn.BookID
    select new { booknn.title, Book_AuthorID = Book_Authornn.Book_Author };
```

Note the inclusion of the two `.ToArray()` calls.

I had to fix some of you variable names and I made a bit of a guess on getting the Author ID.

Does this work for you?

I would suggest only having a single repository and allowing normal joining to occur - loading all objects into memory can be expensive.

If you are making custom repositories you make also consider making a custom method that returns the title and author IDs as a defined class rather than as anonymous classes. Makes for better testability.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

There are more problem after I used your advice. If you are still interrested in solving problem you can go to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666775/what-code-in-inherit-part"

// Fullmetalboy